# Puppet - service state fact

Tags: puppet, facter

Could some one give me quick answer if it is possible to get Service state using puppet facter?

Basically in the Host facts section I would like to see:

```
Apache: Running, version x.x.x
```

Could someone point me to a right direction at least, on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you still interested in the answer to this? I notice you accepted an answer that did not answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I mainly excepted it because I thought that the question might appear too abstract and went reading Puppet documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the commands `apache status` and `apache --version`. If that's what you are looking for. If you are looking to implement it in a manifest then it is a totally different question.